# What exactly should i do at haproxy.cfg

Tags: php, openshift, haproxy

My php application works fine but sometimes i get

> 504 Gateway Time-out The server didn't respond in time.

i can't get rid of this problem even if i do app restart.

the haproxy log :

```
  [WARNING] 001/175903 (47931) : Server express/local-gear is DOWN, reason: Layer4 timeout, check duration: 2000ms. 0 active and 0 backup servers left. 0 sessions active, 0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue.
[ALERT] 001/175903 (47931) : proxy 'express' has no server available!
[WARNING] 001/175933 (47931) : Server express/local-gear is UP, reason: Layer7 check passed, code: 302, info: "HTTP status check returned code <3C>302<3E>", check duration: 9ms. 1 active and 0 backup servers online. 0 sessions requeued, 0 total in queue.
[WARNING] 001/180043 (47931) : Server express/local-gear is DOWN, reason: Layer4 timeout, check duration: 2001ms. 0 active and 0 backup servers left. 1 sessions active, 0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue.
[ALERT] 001/180043 (47931) : proxy 'express' has no server available!
[WARNING] 001/180113 (47931) : Server express/local-gear is UP, reason: Layer7 check passed, code: 302, info: "HTTP status check returned code <3C>302<3E>", check duration: 19ms. 1 active and 0 backup servers online. 0 sessions requeued, 0 total in queue.
```

the solutions i found on internet is to do changes in `haproxy.cfg option httpchk GET`  but don't know what exactly i should do.

my application is located @ `/app-root/repo/php` folder there i have index.php also i have api folder to access my app api.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to edit your `haproxy.cfg` you can do that by sshing into your app by `rhc ssh <yourApp>` and then editing the `~/haproxy/conf/haproxy.cfg` file. However, please note that custom haproxy config is not supported, so I would recommend to back up the file before making any changes, in case you would need to restore the default config.

After making any config changes, do `rhc app-restart <yourApp>` to restart the app.

Comment: sure, but what should i do at the option httpchk GET? what link should i write

Comment: I thought you're trying to locate the file where you would like to change the URI per some instructions from the mentioned solutions (maybe you can link these in your question). I personally have no experience fine tuning the httpchk config value, perhaps someone else could comment. However, did you notice the 504 occurs only after your gear was idled due to inactivity? (only gears of free accounts are being idled) You can check whether the gear is idled before accessing the app in [the web interface](https://openshift.redhat.com/app/console/applications) -> your app -> status (Idle/Started).